# Set a cookie to the entire domain from a page inside a folder

Tags: php, setcookie

I'm a begginer in cookies and stuff like that.

I need to set a cookie to the entire domain from a page inside a folder like `mydomain.com/folder/page.php`. I had to do this before and I got it done redirecting to another page `mydomain.com/another.php` which set the cookies. The thing is now I should not redirect the page because of some data coming from a form and other things, so how could I do this?

`setcookie("name", $name, time()+31536000);` will set the cookies only for the pages inside `folder` and I tried `setcookie("name", $name, time()+31536000,'/','mydomain.com');` but it didn't worked.

Comment: Just remove the domain name part. I think it will work.

Comment: either one of these commands should work, did you check your error.log for errors?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code definitely works:

```
setcookie("name", $value, time()+31536000,'/');
```

You should take note that `mydomain.com` is different from `www.mydomain.com` or `sub.mydomain.com`.

Other than this, take note that the value of `$value` should be a string.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really worked. Sorry for taking so much time to accept it, though. You've answered like 4 days ago.

Answer (score 3):

@SPL_Splinter: Make sure you're setting the cookie prior to *any* output. So, for example:

```
<?php
$name = 'Some name';

setcookie("name", $name, time() + 31536000, '/', '.mydomain.com');
if (isset($_COOKIE['name'])) 
{
    echo $_COOKIE['name'];
}
?>
```

**Update**

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> The domain that the cookie is available to. To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com (including example.com itself) then you'd set it to '.example.com'. Although some browsers will accept cookies without the initial ., » RFC 2109 requires it to be included. Setting the domain to 'www.example.com' or '.www.example.com' will make the cookie only available in the www subdomain.